# Selectize.js - backspace to clear the field doesnt work on mobile browser

Tags: selectize.js

Updated on 02/12/2020:

- Github URL.

---

I'm using the latest selectize.js (Released 0.12.1) and android (chrome browser). For some reasons the component is not working properly on a mobile browser. Below is the steps to reproduce the issue. Any suggestion or workaround would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

1) Go to selectize demo page on your mobile browser - https://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

2) Scroll down to this example

[image]

3) Click on the field to edit it.

4) Now try doing a backspace to clear up the field... it wont work.

Thanks for the help in advance!! : )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok found a solution. There is a plugin called "restore_on_backspace" that did the trick. Hope this help others.

```
<script src="../src/plugins/restore_on_backspace/plugin.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#select-repo').selectize({
        plugins: ['restore_on_backspace']
    }
</script>
```